# endeca property value in lowercase

Tags: properties, lowercase, endeca

I have to store value in one Endeca property but in lowercase. Values can be in uppercase or in lowercase in the source file but I have to store it in lowercase in the Endeca property.

Any pointer on how I can proceed will be helpful.

Thanks
Neha

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using oracle endeca developer studio.

1) Firstly open your pipeline using developer studio which is in app path under config folder.

2) Then under the project explorer window, click on dimension tab.

3) Finally at the top pane, click on values to add for the property you want.

4) Run the baseline update.

Comment: Hi Kareem
Thanks for help...but I want the lowercase values in Properties but with your suggesstion it seems for dimension. Any pointer for that, becoz from my data source I am getting capital value for the field which I have to save into lowercase in Endeca.

Comment: Via with what means are you storing the value for your endeca properties. this could be using DB or any thing. so pass the value on the same and it would reflect the same

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved either adding Java manipulator or Pearl Manipulator in the Endeca pipeline and put the code to convert the value from any case to lower case.

I hope this helps.

Thanks,
Ajay Agrawal